# How to do subcomments

Tags: python, django, web, models

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=120, default=None)
    post_text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_comment = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    comment_text = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.author
```

Hello, i've got a question. How to preform displaying comment as a thread if i have models like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment can have multiple subcomments, so this model won't work. Replace `sub_comment` with `parent = models.ForeignKey(..., related_name='subcomments')`. Then you will be able to say `comment.subcomments` which will give you a related object manager, so `comment.subcomments.all()` will be a query of all subcomments that you can iterate over.